# Fairly complex excel decision formula. Data processing

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sorting

I am not sure where can I ask my question, but after a small research I decided to ask here:

[If I had a question with Excel, which site would I use? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155487/if-i-had-a-question-with-excel-which-site-would-i-use)

---

I have a question regarding the following table:

[Empty table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY1DA.png)

In *Input A — Cell B4* we put a positive number and in *Input B — Cell B7* we put also a positive number. Regarding the pregiven table *Value A*, *Value B* and *Value C* — *Array D3:I9* with all of the so depicted values (these values can be random, in my case I just used the prime numbers), I need a way to generate an output in *Output C — K6*.

The relations to produce a value for the Output is the following:
The number in *Input A — Cell B4* is related to *Value A — Array D3:D7* and the number in *Input B — Cell B7* is related to *Value B — Array E3:I7*. The combination between the *Value A* and *Value B* is related with *Value C — Array E9:I9*.

(1) The *Input A* generates *Value A* by picking from *Array D3:D7* the smallest number bigger than the value in *B4*.

(2) The *Input B* can only be consequent to *Input A*. When *Value A* is generated, *Value B* is on the same **row** as *Value A*, at the same time *Value B* is the biggest number in *Array E[ROW_VALUE_A]:I[ROW_VALUE_A]*.

(3) The *Output C* can only be generated after we generate the *Value B*. The *Value C* is the only number that is found on the same **column** as *Value B*.

(4) *Output C* reads *Value C*.

---

Since this is a little complicated to explain, I feel like giving an example will make things smoother:

(1) If we put number *2,6* in *B4*, the *Value A* has to go *Cell D4 — 3*, because *3* is the smallest number in *Array D3:D7*.
[Stage 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9gPs.png)

(2) This therefore leads us to narrowing down our array to pick *Value B* from *Array E4:I4*. In this array the smallest value bigger than *Input B — B7* is *79 — Cell H4*. *79 — Cell H4* will be our *Value B*.
[Stage 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZJKB.png)

(3) Since *79* is in *Cell H4*, the only number from the column, that goes in *Values C — Array E9:I9* is *139 — H9*.
[Stage 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vsY6.png)

(4) Obviously we print *H9* to *K6*.
[Stage 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpHYY.png)

---

If somebody asked me how to achieve this, I will not be very encouraged, so I will show you my progress so far:

(1) I managed to pick the smallest value from array *Value A — D3:D7*, bigger than *Input A — B4*. The formula is the following:

```
=MIN(IF((D3:D7>=B4)*(D3:D7);(D3:D7)))
```

Which has to be applied with **ctrl**+**shift**+**enter**, as it is an array formula.

Regarding (2) and (3) I don't know how to force the above formula over the array determined by the row of the *Value A*.

If I manage to read the coordinates of the cell to the *Value A — Array D3:D7*, this problem is probably solved.

Here I apply the file, so if anybody is interested, could give it a try:
[The Exel File](https://srv-file2.gofile.io/download/ijJDZn/NormesEurocompompositiondesglass.xlsx)

---

I prefer not to do it with coding in Macros, but with an "in-cell" formula typed in *Output C — K6*.

Thank you for your attention and good luck! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following formula for your exact example material. Naturally, you might alter it to suit larger tables or perhaps you might use Named Ranges for portions of it.

It is an array formula, the CSE variety, so I'll present it WITH the brackets, but naturally only copy and paste what is in-between:

```
{=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,MATCH(MIN(IF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(IF(D3:D7>B4,D3:D7)),D3:D7,0)+2,5),":",ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(IF(D3:D7>B4,D3:D7)),D3:D7,0)+2,9)))>B7,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(IF(D3:D7>B4,D3:D7)),D3:D7,0)+2,5),":",ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(IF(D3:D7>B4,D3:D7)),D3:D7,0)+2,9))))),INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(IF(D3:D7>B4,D3:D7)),D3:D7,0)+2,5),":",ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(IF(D3:D7>B4,D3:D7)),D3:D7,0)+2,9))),0)+4))}
```

(I left the cell references in it relative to make it easier to read. You might $$ them, or prehaps replace them with Named Ranges for each.)

It can be extended by adjusting the cell and range references. 2,000 rows? Then ":D2002" rather than ":D7" and so on. If using Named Ranges for those items, you only need make one alteration for each range reference (all the "D3:D7" bits in the formula), and similarly if you move the input cells (B4 and B7).

Basically you:

1)  Use:

```
=MIN(IF(D3:D7>B4,D3:D7))
```

to find the proper result given Input A. Easy enough, but where is it in the range?

2)  Use MATCH() to locate its row in range D3:D7. Perhaps the last row, row 5 of that range. Add 2 to it since there are 2 rows above it, to get the row of the spreadsheet (not the range) it is in. You already knew the columns are 5 and 9 (E and I) and now you know the row. Put that all together to get the range you want to examine using Input B.

3)  In the formula above, I used the ADDRESS function to build the range to examine against Value B to illustrate the bigger picture:  you might need to create these all dynamically. I balked at completely doing so and used what I knew for figuring the columns, but if the table would never grow, or only every blue moon, you could replace what is inside the INDIRECT() functions with INDIRECT() wrapping a simple concatenation of the row learned in 2) and the two column letters rather than all the ADDRESS() effort.

4)  Either way, having found the value inputs A and B led to, use MATCH() to find its column and build one last INDIRECT(ADDRESS()) portion to create the address in the Values C that you need.

5)  That returns the value you are seeking, so as long as you remember to CSE it, you are in business.

Personally, I hate complexity in spreadsheets so I use Named Ranges as mentioned earlier (clarity AND easier to extend as the spreadsheet is used) and I would also put the raw bits of this formula into Named Ranges so that I could easily upgrade them as I use the spreadsheet over time. Then instead of having a nightmare to piece apart and re-understand before I could upgrade or extend it, I could do the parts bit by bit in their Named Ranges. If your tables could ever grow, especially if they could grow all the time and unpredictably, that approach would really help you manage the process.

Source:  I took the formula in 1), above, from this site:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4279-excel-find-closest-nearest-value-greater-than-less-than.html

Answer (score 0):

This was an excellent reply, thank you — it solved my issue.

Since it was written with *commas* and my Excel due to some Windows setting prefers *semicolons*, I will use your solution and convert it with *semicolons*, so users like me can copy the solution directly:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9;MATCH(MIN(IF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(IF(D3:D7>B4;D3:D7));D3:D7;0)+2;5);":";ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(IF(D3:D7>B4;D3:D7));D3:D7;0)+2;9)))>B7;INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(IF(D3:D7>B4;D3:D7));D3:D7;0)+2;5);":";ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(IF(D3:D7>B4;D3:D7));D3:D7;0)+2;9)))));INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(IF(D3:D7>B4;D3:D7));D3:D7;0)+2;5);":";ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(IF(D3:D7>B4;D3:D7));D3:D7;0)+2;9)));0)+4))
```

Do not forget to apply the formula in the cell with **ctrl**+**shift**+**enter**!

I am now about to go trough the explanation of the formula, since you put some emphasis for us to understand it.

Once again — thank you for your help and keep up with the good work!